# How to Create a Text box in C# form so that user can select a cell

Tags: c#, excel, forms, visual-studio, vsto

Basically, once a form is opened. the form has a textbox where the user can focus on the text box and select any cell from the sheet. so that the cell Address get picked up as well as the Value

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Antt.jpg)

I'm using Vsto Add-in from Visual Studio

At the moment when my form opens, I cannot select any cell or even focus on anything on the sheet.

I have tried this

Excel.Range myRange;

myRange =  (Excel.Range) Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.InputBox("Please select your range?", "Range Selector", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 8);

this works but using this method open up a second window where I need to select the cell

I'm looking for more like a RefEdit control  in excel VBA to add to my Vsto form

Comment: From your example, I Could not understand your question well. Could you show your current code so that I can better solve the problem for you? You need to provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following can help you:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace TestingPurposes
{
   public partial class Main : Form
   {
      public Main()
      {
        InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void ActiveC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        Range R = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveCell;
        ActiveC.Text =Convert.ToString(R.Value);
      }
   }
}
```

Your text box can look like
[image]

You can use the property for the form TopMost as True or False. I used True

Every time you click on the textbox, this will take the value from the active cell.